# Connect IOIO Bridge with android_x86 in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, android-x86, bridge, ioio

**Situation: Connecting IOIO Bridge to android_x86 in Virtualbox**

```
*adb connected to 10.10.10.3:5555 (where 10.10.10.3 is VBox)* 

adb forward tcp:4545 tcp:5555 
java -jar ioiobridge.jar  COM3
```

The output Seems

```
Connecting to IOIO... Connected!
Connecting to Android application... Connected!
Bridge is running...
Bridge closed.
Connecting to IOIO... Connected!
Connecting to Android application... Connected!
Bridge is running...

Bridge closed.
Connecting to IOIO... Connected!
Connecting to Android application... Connected!
Bridge is running...
Bridge closed.
Connecting to IOIO... Connected!
Connecting to Android application... Connected!
Bridge is running...
Bridge closed.
Connecting to IOIO... Connected!
Connecting to Android application... Connected!
Bridge is running...
Bridge closed.
```

what am i going wrong ?

can anyone guess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I Found the answer**,

Its Because the Android Program is Closing the connection 
Reason:Error with opening IOIO Instance 
(i **haven't** used AbstactIOIOActivity or its new version , i am working around IOIO Factory)

if any one in future faces the problem the error is in programming side establishing connection,just use IOIO Libs ,otherwise do a roundup job to create your own as i did.